# A particular quadratic minimization problem

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given $n^2$ constants $a_{11},a_{12},\ldots,a_{1n},a_{21},\ldots,a_{nn}$ and $n^2$ **non-negative** variables $x_{11},x_{12},\ldots,x_{1n},x_{21},\ldots,x_{nn}$. Find the minimum value of $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij}\right)^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}\right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n  \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_{ij}.$$

Even for $n=2$ the problem is not trivial at all for me:

Find the minimum value of 
$$
f(x,y,z,t) = (x+y)^2 + (z+t)^2 + (x+z)^2 + (y+t)^2 + ax + by +cz +dt$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are constants and $x,y,z,t\ge 0$ are variables.

Thank you in advance for your discussion.

Comment: Where is the sum over $j$ for the last $a_{ij}$.. term?

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, I've corrected.

Answer (score 3):

The presence of non-negativity constraints on $x$ suggests that there is no way to guarantee that there will be an analytic solution to this problem, at least not without further information about the values $a_{ij}$. Or did the person who posed this question to you believe that they can make such a guarantee?

What you have here is
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \|Xe\|_2^2 + \|X^Te\|_2^2 + \langle A,X \rangle \\
\text{subject to} & x_{ij} \geq 0, ~ i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}
\end{array}$$
where $e$ is the vector of all ones. This is actually a convex simple quadratic program, but with some Kronecker structure that makes it a bit more difficult to express. If you use a convex modeling framework like [YALMIP](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/) or [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) (disclaimer: the latter is mine) you can express it rather simply. For example, in CVX, the model is

```
cvx_begin
    variable X(n,n)
    minimize(sum_square(sum(X,1))+sum_square(sum(X,2))+trace(A'*X))
    subject to
        X >= 0
cvx_end
```

EDIT: For grins I decided see how far one could get with an analytic solution. It's not easy working with matrix variables! This is the Lagrangian:
$$L(X,Z) = \|Xe\|_2^2+\|X^Te\|_2^2+\langle A,X \rangle - \langle Z,X\rangle$$
where $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ contains the Lagrange multipliers for the nonnegativity constraints; it is elementwise nonnegative. The gradient of the Lagrangian is
$$2ee^T X + 2 X ee^T + A - Z = 0$$
To see how I arrived at this, note that
$$\|Xe\|_2^2=e^TX^TXe=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TXee^T)=\langle X, Xee^T \rangle \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \nabla_X \|Xe\|_2^2 = 2Xee^T$$
$$\|X^Te\|_2^2=e^TXX^Te=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^Tee^TX)
= \langle X, ee^TX \rangle \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \nabla_X \|X^Te\|_2^2 = 2ee^TX$$
I believe this is what we get if we look at an individual term $(i,j)$:
$$2\sum_p X_{pj}+2\sum_{q} X_{iq} + A_{ij} - Z_{ij} = 0, \quad i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$$
It's interesting that the optimality conditions depend only on the $2n$ row and column sums. I am sure that can be exploited somehow. Also, note that if I treat $Z_{ij}$ as a slack variable, I get
$$\sum_p X_{pj}+\sum_{q} X_{iq} \leq \tfrac{1}{2} A_{ij}, \quad i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$$
I'm going to be honest, I'm not yet sure what I'd do from here---if anything. Since existing optimization frameworks handle this problem simply, I'm not sure I'd bother to try for an analytic solution. Still, even if an analytic solution does not exist, exploiting the structure of this problem could help you arrive at much faster approaches to solving the problem numerically.

Comment: Woah, it's nice to get an answer from the author of the well-known CVX :D I'm actually a CVX user (but still a newbie :P) Thank you for developing CVX and making it available to the community.
----

I'm solving a large scale problem using ADMM and the above quadratic program is the subproblem I have to solve at each iteration. As there are so many subproblems (hundreds of thousands), I thought it would be ideal if each problem has a closed-form solution. (continued below)

Comment: But it's not that trivial and I think I will have to use an iterative method. Using CVX's quadratic solver is too slow. As you pointed out, the problem has a special structure to be exploited. I know interior point methods are powerful for structured problems, but besides, there are other efficient methods for nonnegative quadratic programming such as active set, multiplicative update, etc... I would really appreciate your advice :D  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Eh, if you need to go large-scale, then a projected gradient method is going to be a good bet---*possibly* a Nesterov-accelerated gradient; but because this appears to be strongly convex, standard projected gradient should do quite nicely. In that case, at least my expressions for the gradients of the quadratic terms will be helpful.

Comment: And of course with projected gradients, you might be able to re-use the result from the previous subproblem to accelerate each additional solve, something else you can't do in CVX.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.
My original problem has the form: 
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & f(x)+g(z) \\
\text{subject to} & Ax+Bz=c.
\end{array}$$
I tried first using subgradient but it took too many iterations to converge (although it was very fast at each iteration). Then I proceeded with ADMM, which was shown to have better convergence properties (according to Prof. Boyd's paper: http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/admm_distr_stats.html).

Comment: For my problem, for each update $x^{k+1} = \arg\min_{x} L_\rho(x,z^k,y^k)$ (equation 3.2 in the paper) I have to solve $\min_{x} L_\rho(x,z^k,y^k)$, which can be separated into $N$ quadratic programs (the one I posted above) where $N$ is very large (hundreds of thousands).  

Maybe Nesterov-accelerated gradient is another option than ADMM. Time to read papers :D

Comment: And maybe separating the problem is not a good idea in this case (because the number of separated components are too large).

Comment: I'm not sure Nesterov will work for the larger problem due to the equality constraints, unless perhaps you are willing to relax it to $f(x)+g(x)+\mu\|Ax+Bz-c\|_2^2$. Your problem is scale, really, not algorithm choice. If you can distribute the smaller QPs, you win; if not, you lose. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your discussion! :D